# The automorphisms of the Cayley diagram of the cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, cyclic-groups, cayley-graphs

Statements:

1) The automorphisms of the **colored Cayley digraph** of group $G$, is equal to the group $G$ itself. I assumed this is true based on the proof sketch of Frutch's theorem.

2) But then consider the automorphisms of a cycle of length N. This cycle is the Cayley graph of the cyclic group $C_N$. However its automorphism group is the Dihadral group $D_N$.

Which one of my statements is wrong?

Comment: Neither of them is wrong. As a graph, we have a cycle of length N and its automorphism group is dihedral. On the other hand,  as a colored Cayley digraph on a cyclic group, you have to replace edges by arcs in each direction, and those arcs have different colors (inverses of each other), so that "reflection" is no longer an automorphism.

Comment: Seems so obvious now! Thanks, that was killing me.